# How to manipulate String count in JSON in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

In one use case I need to write a Query which return **1** if string count is >=**4** or else return **0**.

Below is the JSON which contains string.[image]

Below is the query, which is returning a single row.

```
   Select * from [Frs_def_businessobjectlayouts] where Definition like '%Open In Parent%' AND name like 
    'Task.ResponsiveAnalyst'
```

Note - **Definition is the column which contains JSON data**

Could some one help me out here!!.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to query the JSON and store in a temp variable and declare the word you want to search in another variable and perform the below operation. You will get the number of times it occurred in the JSON as output.

```sql
DECLARE @string VARCHAR(MAX)="Query your JSON from the table and assign to this variable"
 
DECLARE @tosearch VARCHAR(MAX)='Open In Parent'  
  
SELECT (DATALENGTH(@string)-DATALENGTH(REPLACE(@string,@tosearch,'')))/DATALENGTH(@tosearch)  
AS OccurrenceCount
```